# How can I register an SSRS server in SSMS and connect to it?

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms, ssrs

Under the Registered Servers window, I switched to Reporting Services and created a new server registration. By way of trial and error I figured that the Test button would succeed if I entered http://ip_address/ReportServer for the server name (the IP alone or a full URL of the SSRS ASMX would not work), chose Basic or Forms Authentication and provided the user name and password. Then it tested Okay and saved.

Now that I am trying to connect to the newly registered server, I get the following error:

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Error connecting to 'http://192.168.0.4/ReportServer'.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Value does not fall within the expected range. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.RSClient)
```

I noticed that after I save the new server registration, the Authentication drop down always reverts to Windows Authentication and blanks out the user name and password, even though I am specifying Forms/Basic, testing that successfully, and saving thereafter.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use windows auth and server name syntax should be servername\instancename.

Comment: To use Windows auth I would need to be a user on the SSRS server, which is not the case.

Comment: Then someone who are need to configure basic or form authentication and add you in such way before you can use them. They are not default settings for SSRS.

Comment: Read the section about register a report server. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/connect-to-a-report-server-in-management-studio

Comment: And you don't need to be a user in the server but you need to be added as a user in SSRS to be able to connect.

Comment: This will never be the case

Answer (score -1):

- To connect to the server you need to use the servername or ip, if its a named instance you need to use servername\instancename.
- To use Basic or Form Authentication you need to configure it. Read more about login with Basic and Form Auth here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/connect-to-a-report-server-in-management-studio

[image]
[image]

Form and Basic login must be configured before you are able to use them and SQL Login is not supported.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/authentication-with-the-report-server

Comment: When using the syntax you proposed, the login times out. And the saved server is still reverting to Windows auth. What am I missing?

Comment: You need to use Windows auth like i wrote or Configure form or basic.

Comment: Do you know the instance name?